# Update row with more that one item?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my products table

[image]

And here is my cart table

[image]

When the transaction is finished i would like to update my products table(sizes) only with `$new_quantity`

My code looks like:

```
$cartQ=$db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id='{$cart_id}'");
    $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
    $items=json_decode($result['items'],true);
    foreach ( $items as $item) {

        $product_id = $item['id'];
        $product_quantity=$item['quantity'];
        $product_size=$item['size'];
        $productQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='{$product_id}'");
        $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
        $productSizes=$product['sizes'];
        $sArray = explode(',', $productSizes);

        foreach ($sArray as $sizeString) {
            $s = explode(':', $sizeString);
            $size=$s[0];
            $quantity=$s[1];
            $threshold=$s[2];

        }
    }
    $quantity_updateQ=$db->query("SELECT sizes FROM products WHERE id='{$product_id}'");
    $quantity_update=mysqli_fetch_assoc($quantity_updateQ);
    $new_quantity=intval($quantity-intval($product_quantity));
    echo $new_quantity;
    var_dump($product_id);
    $quantity_finished=$db->query("UPDATE products SET sizes= '{$new_quantity}' WHERE id='{$product_id}'");
```

Comment: Normalize your products table with an additional "sizes" table so that it's more efficient and easier to update.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: For example in sizes i have S:5:2,M:4:2 (M and S is sizes)(5,4 is my quantity for the sizes)(2,2 is threshold) , when the transaction is finished and the user have bought product with S size and quantity 2, i would like to update my database and  тhe quantity to be reduced(to be S:3:2)